# Какой же тип речи все-таки?

Tags: типы-речи

> > Все помнится в черном цвете: **черные танки, черные мотоциклы, немецкие
> > > солдаты в черной форме.** Я не уверен, что все это было на самом деле
> > > только черным, но я так запомнил. Так оно лежит в памяти…

Не могу до конца сообразить, какой тут тип речи - рассуждение или рассуждение с элементами описания (то, что смущает, подчеркнула ).

---

> Задание звучит так: "В предложениях . . . представлено рассуждение". (верно)

Comment: По-моему, здесь не рассуждение, а **повествование**. Но, может, я и ошибаюсь…

Comment: Тут же нет последовательных действий персонажа. Как-то странновато было бы считать этот именно повествованием.