# Как правильно определить тип речи?

Tags: типы-речи

**Какие признаки** имеют разные типы речи: **повествование, описание, рассуждение**?

Возможно ли **совмещение разных типов** речи в одном тексте?

Каковы особенности рассуждения в **художественной речи**?

Answer (score 1):

Материал дан **по [книге](https://books.google.ru/books?id=bOFgDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=ru#v=onepage&q&f=false)**

**Бабайцева В.В. Русский язык. 10 — 11 кл.** Учебник для общеобразовательных учреждений **филологического** профиля, 8-е изд. 2011 год.

**Повествование**

1. Динамичность, движение. Изменение во времени.
2. Цепной вид связи: 1 —2 —3 —4…  Тема задана в первом предложении, далее названы события.
3. Слова: как-то раз, однажды (начальный момент).  Далее одно действие сменяется другим. Временные наречия: сначала, потом, наконец.
4. Глаголы совершенного вида СВ. Единичные глаголы НСВ обозначают продолжительность или повторяемость действий.
5. Возможны назывные предложения: Сад, подворье, белый  дом. Зашумели верхушки лип. Свет. Удар грома.

**Описание**

1. Указание на признаки и свойства различных предметов (человек, животные, природа и т.д.).
2. Параллельная связь. Тема задана в первом предложении, далее признак 1, признак 2…
3. Статичность, фиксированный момент времени, один кадр фильма.
4. Глаголы НСВ, именные сказуемые.
5. Время фиксируется для наблюдателя,  но природа  может сохранять движение (динамичность в статике): играют волны, ветер свищет, и мачта гнется и скрипит.

**Рассуждение**

1. Устанавливается причинная взаимосвязь событий и явлений по схеме:  тезис (утверждение, которое надо доказать) — доказательство (аргументы, доводы) — вывод, итог.
2. Слова: во-первых, во-вторых, конечно, возможно, главное, потому что, следовательно, значит.

**Особенности рассуждения в художественной речи**

(1) Внутренняя речь персонажей: присутствуют не все части рассуждения; отступления, вставки, разговорный стиль, хаотичность речи.

(2) Медитативные тексты (раздумья, размышления): слова нет и да; вопросительные предложения.

**Совмещение разных типов речи**

Повествование может сменяться описанием:  Тогда движение  во времени останавливается, наблюдатель фиксирует определенный момент,  динамика сменяется статикой.

Текст может начинаться с рассуждения, а потом переходить в описание (украинская ночь у Гоголя начинается с вопроса: знаете ли вы…)

**ПРИМЕР**

**[Какой же тип речи все-таки?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/480263/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8)**

**С. Алексиевич**

(1) **Повествование + описание эпизодов.**

```
  Грузим на телегу узлы, меня усаживают на них… 
  Куда-то едем… Потом возвращаемся… 
  У нас в доме – немцы! Они похожи на наших солдат, 
  только в другой форме и веселые.  
  По улице мимо нашего дома ведут человека в горелой 
  гимнастерке, босиком,  со связанными проволокой 
  руками. Человек весь черный… 
  Потом я видел его повешенным возле сельсовета. 
  Говорили, что это наш летчик. 
  Ночью он мне приснился. Во сне он висел у нас во 
  дворе…
```

(2) **Рассуждение**

```
 Из тех дней… Все помнится в черном цвете: черные 
 танки, черные мотоциклы, немецкие солдаты в черной 
 форме. Я не уверен, что все это было на самом деле 
 только черным, но я так запомнил. Так оно лежит в 
 памяти…
```

В этом эпизоде есть **только рассуждение,** внутренний монолог героя.  Говорится о том, что все впечатления того времен окрашены в черный цвет. Приводится размышление о том, были ли они действительно черными или просто казались такими. Здесь **нет описания в конкретный момент** времени,  но есть **обобщение** воспоминаний.